# Spring 3.0 Could not load properties

Tags: java, spring, apache, jakarta-ee, netbeans

Im the getting the following Error/exception when deploying web app:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could
>   not load properties; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/WebAppProps]

Below is the context tag that Im using in **applicationContext.xml** to point to **WebAppsProps.properties** file

```
   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="classpath:/WEB-INF/WebAppProps.properties" />
```

**I have also used:**

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/WebAppProps.properties" />
```

The file is actualy in the filesystem & below is the snapshot of my project structure:

[image]

I also tried , putting "WebAppProps.properties" on the classpath and used these 2 variations

**variation 1:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
        <property name="location"> 
            <value>classpath:WebAppProps.properties</value> 
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

**variation 2:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
        <property name="location"> 
            <value>WebAppProps.properties</value> 
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

Please see below: 
[image]

However Im still getting same error/exception.

Please Advise

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Same issue i crossed,

**Fix:** 
**Solution** 
your bean like below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>/WEB-INF/database.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

create folder properties under `WEB-INF` it look like `WEB-INF/properties/database.properties`

because the class `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` default search properties folder first under `/WEB-INF/` so it concatenate your file name as path

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should change your code and put the properties like that :

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring 4 this is how I would configure the properties file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "${application.properties}", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
})
public class WebServiceConfig {
---
}
```

And when starting my tomcat in setenv.sh I define the path as

```
-Dapplication.properties=file:location-of-file/application.properties"
```

Notice file: prefix here. That is important.

Now you can drop file anywhere on your file system and  change the path without ever changing the code

Comment: I had to leave out the "file:" prefix. Otherwise I got an error "could not find file:file:appication.properties"

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">
        <value>WebAppProps.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Just put the file on the classpath in the root of the `classes` directory.

Comment: I tried putting "WebAppProps.properties" on classpath under root of "src" so during build/deploying it gets put in the root of classes dir, after deployment I reconfirmed the "WebAppProps.properties" was put under ../classes/. However I still get the sam exception & app failes to deploy.

Comment: classpath:WebAppProps.properties.   Of note here is that WEB-INF is not available in your classpath (only the classes directory, and what's in lib/*.jar).  It's even entirely possible that the WEB-INF directory may not even be decompressed, or put in a wierd location by your container (as opposed to the easy to find location in tomcat).  You might want to use the ServletContext version of the placeholder, so you can not have to modify the war or exploded war file.  You could just supply context parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

if you dont need to get the bean, but only the properties:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/WebAppProps.properties" file-encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

or if you need the bean (it may happens you want to inject your properties bean, if you need to read many props...)

```
<bean id="configProperty" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
               <value>/WEB-INF/config.properties</value>
               <value>/WEB-INF/setup.properties</value>
           </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```