# Load a property file when context is loading giving the file path as a property of another property file

Tags: java, spring

I have a situation where I need to use two property files in my system.

1. System.properties

   ```
   key.supportiveFile=C:\keypath\supportive.properties
   ```

   This **key path** which can be outside the classpath. I want to maintain path for the 
    Supportive.properties as a key in System.properties.  The supportive.properties file has
2. supportive.properties.

   Supportive.properties has keys key1 , key2. 
   properties in the **supportive.properties file must load with the context**.

Ideally my property files will be appear as below.

```
supportive.properties
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

In spring.xml I tried to load the supportive.properties and inject key1 and key2 value defined in spring.xml like below.

i. Loading the property files

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:System.properties,file:${key.supportiveFile}"/>
```

ii. This is a sample bean how I want to inject my keys to a bean.

```
    <bean id="helloWorldBean" class="com.sample.snippets.enterprise.services.HelloWorld">
         <property name="prefixProp" value="${key1}" />
         <property name="suffixProp" value="${key2}" /> 
    </bean>
```

Server log says  `Could not resolve placeholder 'key.supportiveFile' in [file:${key.supportiveFile}]`  but it fails and not loading the supportive.property file.

Please advise how to fix this technically.

Comment: please use the proper text-format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar.config"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="file:${key.supportiveFile}" />

<bean id="helloWorldBean" class="com.sample.snippets.enterprise.services.HelloWorld">
    <property name="prefixProp" value="${key1}" />
    <property name="suffixProp" value="${key2}" /> 
</bean>
```

and inside `com.foo.bar.config` you have the following class:

```
package com.foo.bar.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/System.properties")
public class SpringConfig{

}
```

Explanation for this approach comes from [this JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6428).

Comment: Thanks I tried with your approach but unfortunately now I am getting the below error when loading the file:${key.supportiveFile} resource.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627856/spring-3-0-could-not-load-properties

Comment: What exactly did you try? Show us your code and the stack trace!

Comment: Sorry, it was a windows path issue. This works fine with Spring3.x. The actual implementation I want to apply to a project with Spring version 2.5.1 where it does not have org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration class. Is there a way to do in such cases. ?

Comment: Is it possible to use only <context:property-placeholder to load the property file without SpringConfig class. I need to apply this change to Spring 2.5.1 where the Configuration class is not present? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. I know I tried some time ago to use two property placeholders with different suffixes ("$" and "%") and one to reference a placeholder of the other. Couldn't make it work.